# ANOVA and post-test for expression data in R

Tags: r, anova

I have a dataset of expression values from 3 groups (proteome expression data as log2).
Now I would like to perform first an ANOVA to check for proteins differentially expressed in any of the 3 groups and next perform a post-test (eg Tukeys) to figure out which proteins are affected in which specific group comparison.

Unfortunately, no resources I found discussed this rather simple case but only much more complicated cases with multiple group combinations (and eg two treatments).

With the HybridMTest package, the ANOVA went fine and I have now the FDR for differentially expressed proteins between the 3 groups (6 samples per group).
But now I'm stuck on how to calculate the posttest for every protein (= rows, n = 3878) between all of the 3 groups.

I could not find an appropriate package or function, maybe one of you could offer a hint on how to solve this? I would like to obtain as a result a df with the protein_id, the comparison group, the FDR and the logFoldChange.

Many thanks!
(and sorry for providing the data only in a very descriptive way. I dont know how to create example expression data but will look into it)

Sebastian

---

Data description:

expression_df:
rownames(expression_df) = protein_id, colnames(expression_df) = sample_id

pheno_df:
rownames(pheno_df) = sample_id, pheno_df$cluster = cluster group (n=3)

anova_results:
rownames(protein_id), anova_results$FDR = FDR controlled ANOVA result

Comment: is base `TukeyHSD()` not an option?

Comment: The function takes an aov object. These objects contain only data from one row but I would need to do this for 1500 rows and I have not found a way to apply this. If you have a solution it would be great to hear it!

Comment: In response to the above, why not use the `apply` family. There is even a set of apply functions that you can use to run in parallel since you have 1000+ tests to run.